# Orthogonal Projection sequence space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am having some trouble understanding orthogonal projection outside of basic examples from linear algebra. If anybody could help with this example from sequence spaces that would be great.

Let $a , b , c \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

and,

\begin{equation}
a(n) = \frac{1}{n+1} \\  
b(n) = 1 \ \ \ \text{if}  \ \ n = 1,2 \ (0 \  \text{otherwise}) \\ 
c(n) = \frac{1}{n} 
\end{equation}

Compute the orthogonal projection in $l^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ of $a$ onto the span of $b$ and $c$

Comment: Start by just doing the computations, applying formulas. The projection over $b$ is especially easy. Work it out a little, it will become clearer. After you have done that, you can always edit your question and ask for something more precise than just "I am having trouble understanding this and that". HTH

Comment: define your scalar product, then formally plug it into the projection formulae you know from linear algebra. might be a good idea to Gram-Schmidt-izate $\left\{b,c\right\}$, too.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Should I say that $a = [ 1/2, 1/3, .....] b= [1,1,0,0,...] c= [ 1,1/2, 1/3 ....].$
Then find the span of b and c? So is this is the set of all linear combinations of b and c?

Comment: @Max The scalar product is $||a||_2$ I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Let $\left(H,\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>\right)$ be a hilbert space and $h\in H$ a vector. Then $H\ni x\mapsto h\cdot\frac{\left<x,h\right>}{\left<h,h\right>}\in H$ is the orthogonal projection on $\mathrm{span}\left(h\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orthogonality is defined in terms of the dot product. $x \perp y$ iff $\sum_n x(n)\overline{y(n)}=0$. The orthogonal projection of '$a$' onto the span of '$b$' and '$c$' is the same as what you learned in Calculus: You have to find a point $p$ on the plane spanned by $b$ and $c$ such that $(a-p)\perp\mbox{span}\{b,c\}$. The point $p$ is the orthogonal projection of $a$ onto the plane $\mbox{span}\{b,c\}$. Because $p$ is on the plane, then $p=\alpha b + \beta c$ where $\alpha$, $\beta$ are complex scalars. You need to find the scalars $\alpha,\beta$ so that
$$
               (a-\alpha b - \beta c)\perp (\gamma b + \delta c),\;\;\;\mbox{for all }\delta,\gamma \in \mathbb{C}.
$$
That is equivalent to finding $\alpha$, $\beta$ such that
$$
                   (a-\alpha b -\beta c)\perp b \\
                   (a-\alpha b - \beta c)\perp c.
$$
That's two linear equations in the two unknowns $\alpha$, $\beta$, and will have a unique solution if $b$ and $c$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank You, so I have filled in these two linear equations into the orthogonality formula (using the scalar product for $l^{2}$). For the one with $b$, it seems straight forward(the b term disappears after n=2) , as for $c$ , it is not so clear. Do I have to make  asubstitution or is there an observation I am missing?

Comment: Can I use Cauchy Schwarz?

Comment: So $a=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\cdots)$, and $b=(1,1,0,0,0,\cdots)$ and $c=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\cdots)$. You're right that the $\perp b$ equation is not so bad. You can choose any basis for the plane. A convenient one is $b$ and $d=c-\frac{(c,b)}{(b,b)}b$ because those are orthogonal vectors. Then you can solve for $\alpha'$, $\beta'$ as multipliers of $b$ and $d$. That gives you one equation for $\alpha'$ and another for $\beta'$. The answer $\alpha' b+\beta' d$ will be the same as $\alpha b + \beta c$. Has to be by uniqueness; and the final vector is all that counts.